# Magento 2 - How to get data from table customer_log?

Tags: magento2, php, sql

I need to get the value for `last_login_at` for the current customer, but this seems to be impossible without the use of SQL.

[image]

**Current Solution (SQL):**

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
*/
protected $_connection;

...

$connection = $this->_connection->getConnection();
$tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName('customer_log');
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE customer_id = " . $customerId;
$result = $connection->fetchRow($sql);
```

How does it work with Magento code instead of SQL? It seems to me that magento 2 did forgot to implement the proper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following class **get** method by customer id:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Logger.php

```
public function get($customerId = null)
```